# Is possible to avoid the perspective distorsion on a 3D object in a scene with threejs?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I have a scene with some 3d Objects when you drag the scene objects look stretched. See the image

[image: image distorsion]

I know that this is the normal behavior But I have a client with this weird requirement, that the objects should move but without the distortion on the shape.

Is there way to do that?

Comment: Tried to keep their rotation aligned with the camera?

Comment: are those 3d objects or sprites?

Comment: @RienNeVaPlu͢s   yes I tested it and improve a lot but you can still see a little distorsion.

Comment: @gaitat  yes 3d objects

Comment: @SaulBurgos What is the field-of-view of your camera?

Comment: @WestLangley   I am using A-FRAME framework to create the elements and FOV is the camera is 80.

Comment: @SaulBurgos That's the cause. You will have to lower it, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s due to the camets fov. You can change it through the [camera component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/camera.html#properties_fov)

Comment: Thanks Diego, I guess is the only way but elements now look closer